# trying to create a tip calculator

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a tip calculator that uses a method and a loop. inside the loop i have an if statement to sort out the amount of tip. if i try to add the data to empty arrays inside the object, the program stops.

i have tried to use push and still doesnt work. if on the other hand i create a variable and store the data there  and add the end add it it works. i just want to understand why the other way it doesnt work.

If i have a code for example

```
let john = {
  bills: [124, 48, 268, 180,  42],
  tipCalc: function (){
    this.tip = [];
    this.total = [];
    for (let i = 0 ; i < this.bills.length; i++) {
      let bills = this.bills[i]; 
      if (bills < 50)  {
         this.tip[i] = (.2 * bills);
         this.total[i] = (this.tip[i] + bills);
      }
    }
}
```

if i tried something like that why wouldn't it work?

is there anyone that can explain it/

there is no actual result. if i do it like this it works.

```
for (let i =0; i <this.bills.length; i++) {
  let bills = this.bills[i];
  let percentage;
  if (bills < 50) {
     percentage = .2 
  }
  this.tip[i] = percentage * bills; 
}
```

Comment: Other than the fact that you are missing a `}` at the end of the first snippet. What is the problem? Just copied the code to my console and it worked fine.

Comment: so i was trying to see if someone can help me understand why the first code isnot working? when i try to use it it doesnt return any value.

Comment: @Josel That's because there is no `return` statement. Add a `return this.total`, or something similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want 
you call `this.tip = [] and this.total = [];` this inside `tipCalc` function but i dont see that you ever declare it.
second u did not call ur `tipCalc` function

I solve it in below way

```js
let john = {
  bills: [124, 48, 268, 180, 42],
  total: [],
  tip: [],
  tipCalc: function (){
     for (let i = 0 ; i < this.bills.length; i++) {
        let bills = this.bills[i];
        if (bills < 50)  {
           this.tip.push(.2 * bills);
           this.total.push(this.tip + bills);
        }
     }
  }
}
john.tipCalc()
console.log(john.tip)
console.log(john.total)
```

First i call and execute ur function and then call ur tip and total variable

Hope it helps. 
please comments if you have any confusion

***Updated Answer*** 
Another way to complete it

```js
let john = {
  bills: [124, 48, 268, 180, 42],
  tipCalc: function (){
    var total = [];
    var tip =  []
    for (let i = 0 ; i < this.bills.length; i++) {
      let bills = this.bills[i];
      if (bills < 50)  {
          tip.push(.2 * bills);
          total.push(tip + bills);
      }
    }
    total = total.concat(tip);
    return total
  }
}
console.log(john.tipCalc())
```

Comment: hey thanks for the reply
```
let john = {
  bills: [124, 48, 268, 180,  42],
  tipCalc: function (){
    this.tip = [];
    this.total = [];
    for (let i = 0 ; i < this.bills.length; i++) {
      let bills = this.bills[i]; 
      if (bills < 50)  {
         this.tip[i] = (.2 * bills);
         this.total[i] = (this.tip[i] + bills);
      }
    }
}
``
I though that by putting this.tip =[]; in the method, it woudl be declared previous to the if Statement. i didnt call the function because i tried it and it didnt work.
i had solved it first with a solution like that previous.

Comment: ```let john = {
 bills: [124, 48, 268, 180, 42],
 tipCalc: function (){
    this.tip = []; 
    this.total = [];
     for (let i = 0; i < this.bills.length; i++){
        let bills = this.bills[i]; 
        let percentage; 
         if (bills < 50) { 
             percentage = .2;  
         } else if (bills >= 50 && bills <=  200) {
             percentage = .15;
         } else { 
            percentage = .1; 
         }
         this.tip[i] = percentage * bills; 
         this.total[i] = (percentage * bills) + bills; 
     } 
 }, 
}
john.tipCalc(); 
```

Comment: what i am trying to solve is the code in above the comment of u r welcome. i am trying to understand why it doesnt work. did it work for you?

Comment: i think u didn't read my ans. as i said there u called `this.tip = []; this.total = [];` what does that mean. its mean ur previously declare `tip & total` variable but never declare it . second u write `this.tip[i] & this.total[i]` but there has no element in `tip & total` they are empty so you can not call any element. now u call `john.tipCalc();` but inside function u did not return anything so without return what a function can do NOTHING hope you understand

Comment: check my answer i called `total & tip` outside function in but inside JSON now u can refer `this` here this scope means ur complete json object scope not ur  function scope.

Comment: Thx i think that was my doubt, now i understand because i declared everything int he same function it didnt run. i would have to declare it before.

Comment: if you want to declare those variable inside function you can also do this i give another example in my answer plz check it out

Comment: if you declare them inside function u dont need to call this because `this` scope belongs to ur whole json object . and when u call a function u must have to return something otherwise u r not gonna get any update

Comment: wow yeah thats what i was looking for, is there a way to give you double points?

Comment: I am glad it helps. u accept the answer but i dont think u can not give upvote because u don't have enough reputation. But thanks and feel better that i able to help you .

Comment: now sorry another question. is there a way to eliminate the bothArr?
so just have the tip.push and total.push?